# File encrypted on old PC, need to decrypt

Tags: windows, encryption, efs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Through EFS (Encrypted File System)](https://superuser.com/questions/2732/getting-through-efs-encrypted-file-system)

My dad encrypted a file on a PC running Win XP. He got a new PC running Win 7. There were some files encrypted using Windows EFS from the old XP OS in a pen drive, and now we're unable to figure out how to open the same. Help please.

-- Ram

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Through EFS (Encrypted File System)](http://superuser.com/questions/2732/getting-through-efs-encrypted-file-system) also see [What happens with EFS-encrypted files, if I install Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/22977/what-happens-with-efs-encrypted-files-if-i-install-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: Do you still have the old PC? Can you start WinXP and log in to the old account?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I know it's not a programming question. However, I was not sure which forum to post this into. Please excuse. Also, if you see techie007's comment, there are a few more questions of the same kind.

Comment: @techie007 - Thanks for the pointers; guess I hadn't searched well enough.

Comment: @grawity - No chance of doing that, it was a laptop issued by his previous firm and he quit it long back.

Comment: @RamakrishnanRS: In that case, the data is most likely lost. Even Elcomsoft's tool appears to require access to the old system in order to retrieve the keys.

Comment: @grawity Oh! Please convert your comment to an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your dad made a backup of the encryption keys that were on his old laptop, associated with his user-Id on that machine, data in any file encrypted with those keys is now lost.

Microsoft [say](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700811.aspx#XSLTsection134121120120)

> By far, the most frequent problem with EFS occurs when EFS encryption
>   keys and/or recovery keys aren't archived. If keys aren't backed up,
>   they cannot be replaced when lost. If keys cannot be used or replaced,
>   data can be lost. If Windows is reinstalled (perhaps as the result of
>   a disk crash) the keys are destroyed. If a user's profile is damaged,
>   then keys are destroyed. In these, or **in any other cases in which keys
>   are damaged or lost and backup keys are unavailable, then encrypted
>   files cannot be decrypted.** The encryption keys are bound to the user
>   account, and a new iteration of the operating system means new user
>   accounts. A new user profile means new user keys. If keys are
>   archived, or exported, they can be imported to a new account. If a
>   revocation agent for the files exists, then that account can be used
>   to recover the files. However, in many cases in which keys are
>   destroyed, both user and revocation keys are absent and there is no
>   backup, resulting in lost data.

…

> File encryption uses a symmetric key, which is then itself encrypted
>   with the public key of a public key encryption pair. The related
>   private key must be available in order for the file to be decrypted.
>   This key pair is bound to a user identity and made available to the
>   user who has possession of the user ID and password. If the private
>   key is damaged or missing, even the user that encrypted the file
>   cannot decrypt it. If a recovery agent exists, then the file may be
>   recoverable. If key archival has been implemented, then the key may be
>   recovered, and the file decrypted. If not, the file may be lost. **EFS
>   is an excellent file encryption system—there is no "back door."**

(my **emphasis**)

Comment: Extremely detailed explanation, @RedGrittyBrick! Sad news, but a conclusion to the problem nonetheless! Thanks a lot!